# how to store weekly data from google analytics

Tags: api, google-analytics, google-bigquery, etl

I have some simple weekly aggregates from Google analytics that i'd like to store somewhere. The reason for storing is because if I run a query against too much data in google analytics, it becomes sampled and I want it to be totally accurate.

What is the best way to solve this?
My thoughts are:
1) Write a process in bigquery to append the data each week to a permanent dataset
2) Use an API that gets the data each week and stores the data in a google spreadsheet (appending a line each time)

What is the best recommendation for my problem - and how do I go about executing it?

Answer (score 0):

Checking your previous questions, we see that you already use Bigquery.

When you run a query against the Google Analytics tables that is not sampled, as that has all the data in it. There is no need to store as you can query every time you need.

In case if you want to store, and pay for the addition table, you can go ahead store in a destination table.

If you want to access quickly, try creating a view.

Comment: this does not answer my question as I want to know how to actually set up the ETL to do the store. are there such things as stored procedures etc?

Comment: @shecode not sure what you want to store here. There are no stored procedures.

Comment: well rather than pulling the same weekly data every week (including historicals) , i want to insert new weekly data at the end of each week to a table so that this weekly summary is stored somewhere

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following:

1) make a roll-up table for your weekly data - you can do that either by writing a query for it and running manually or with a script in a Google Spreadsheet that uses the same query (using the API) and is scheduled to run every week. I tried a bunch of the tutorials out there and [this one](https://greenido.wordpress.com/2013/12/16/big-query-and-google-spreadsheet-intergration/) is the simplest to implement

2) depending on the data points you want, you can even use the Google Analytics API without having to go through BigQuery for this request, try pulling this report of yours from [here](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/) . If it works there are a bunch of Google Sheets extensions that can make it a lot quicker to set up  a weekly report. Or you can just code it yourself

Would that work for you?

thks!